# Cannot get GET variable by uri segment Codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this following url,

```
localhost/socialmedia/post/?search=andy
```

I want to get "search variable"

but I got this error,

```
Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.
```

Seems like there is something to be setup in routing file,

what should I do?

*info I've been checking to Codeigniter 3.0 Url documentation but no further explanation.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Any given answer will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have enabled

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Then for example your url needs to be

```
http://localhost/socialmedia/?c=post&search=andy
```

Config.php

Change this

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

To

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

And then how to use links below.

```
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
```

And also when using url helper

```
site_url('c=post&search=1234');

application 

application > controllers >

application > controllers > Post.php
```

If in sub directory

```
site_url('d=some_folder&c=post&search=1234');

application 

application > controllers >

application > controllers > some_folder >

application > controllers > some_folder > Post.php
```

It will automatically pick up ? before `d`

You may need to configure your uri routing though.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

in your `config.php`

change this:

```
 $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

to:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

But keep in mind that:

> Enable Query Strings
>
> By default CodeIgniter uses search-engine friendly segment based URLs:
>    example.com/who/what/where/
>
> By default CodeIgniter enables access to the $_GET array.  If for some
>    reason you would like to disable it, set 'allow_get_array' to FALSE.
>
> You can optionally enable standard query string based URLs:
>    example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here
>
> Options are: TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
>
> The other items let you set the query string 'words' that will
>    invoke your controllers and its functions:
>    example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=function
>
> Please note that some of the helpers won't work as expected when
>    this feature is enabled, since CodeIgniter is designed primarily to
>    use segment based URLs.

Comment: how do I get the value with "who=me&what=something&where=here" ?

Comment: `$var =  $this->uri->segment(3); echo $var;`

Comment: is that means that I need to setup the route?

Comment: Depends on the what you are actually after, your code. I would suggest to not use this. Since codeigniter is not built that way. I'm sure you can do whatever you're trying, without this.